# check dictionary is user exists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm taking an OOP approach of creating a login module. I've self initialised a list and a dictionary which both already contain admin and password within it.
Within that class I have created a login function which requests input from a user.
Based on the input I am attempting to write a code to read the dictionary and to return 'logged in' as True if the inputs match of that in the dictionary.
I've been attempting this issue in multiples ways; for loop, calling for the dict.items but its been the same outputs, that the user does not exits

```
class LoginSection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_data = ['admin','password']
        self.username_password = {admin:password}

    def login(self):
        '''
        Login interface
        '''
        logged_in = False
        while not logged_in:

            print("\nLOGIN")
            curr_user = input("Username: ")
            curr_pass = input("Password: ")
            if curr_user not in self.username_password.keys():
                print("User does not exist")
                continue

            if curr_pass != self.username_password[curr_user]:
                print("incorrect password")
                continue

            print("Login Successful!")
            logged_in = True
```

Comment: Your [mre] seems to be missing some critical elements to include: (1) How are you instantiating your ```LoginSection``` class, and (2) How are you calling the ```login``` function.  In addition, once you call the ```login``` function, your while loop will never return.

Comment: This task we were given a task manager to abstract and simplify it with functions. 
I'm new to OOP which is why I am attempting this approach. I thought with this example it would be fairly straight forward.

But I call for this function through 'LoginSection().login()'

Comment: So what exactly happens when you make this call?  Have you tried debugging your code?